# How to add symmetric values with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, symmetric

I have this markup:

```
<div class="container">
   <figure></figure>   
   <figure></figure>
   <figure></figure>
</div>
```

Now: I need to add for each of `figures` a symmetric element, but with different height and width value. For each item next I need to remove about 10% in width and height. So that the first has 90%, the second 80% and the third has 70% of initial size. I'm using the following code but it does not work, can anyone help?

```
var inside_element = $(figure);
var indx = 10;
inside_element.each(function(indx){
    $(this).css({
        width: '90%' - indx,
        height: '90%' - indx
    });
});
```

Thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You working on string '90%' and trying to complete math operation, which will fall. This should work:

```
var inside_element = $('figure');
var indx = 10;
inside_element.each(function(indx){
    $(this).css({
        width: (90 - (10*indx)) + '%' ,
        height: (90 - (10*indx)) + '%'
    });
});
```

Also declaration `var indx = 10;` is not necessary. This value will be overrided inside function.

**EDIT**: Also there can be more containers. Then code should look like this:

```
var inside_container = $('.inside_container');
    inside_container.each( function(i) {
    var inside_element = $(this).find('figure');
    var step = 10;
    inside_element.each(function(indx){
        $(this).css({
            width: (90 - (step*indx)) + '%' ,
            height: (90 - (step*indx)) + '%'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You are missing quotes - $("figure");

Comment: You can leave off the declaration of indx, it's already passed in the .each() callback.

Comment: ok, this work perfectly, but if i will have more than one main containers this action will be execute for every figure since first to last, how to calculate it for only parent wrapper area

Comment: Then you have to update your selector. For example put wrapper id on container, then call: `var inside_element = $('#wrapper figure');`

Comment: i have this and still not working `var inside_container = $('.inside_container'), inside_element = inside_container.find('.element_inside');`

Comment: Is `.element_inside` same element as `figure` in this question?

Comment: yeap this is the same element

Comment: The probably problem lays on simultaneous declaration. Try: `var inside_container = $('.inside_container'); var inside_element = inside_container.find('.element_inside');`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30057/discussion-between-djlukas777-and-kasyx)

Answer (score 1):

You are not selecting `figure` you need this `$('figure');`

```
var inside_element = $('figure');
inside_element.each(function(index){
    $(this).css({
        width: (90 - index * 10) +"%",
        height:(90 - index * 10) +"%"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calulating the next width and hight by substracting `indx` from a String.

try:

```
var width = 100;
var height = 100;
inside_element.each(function(indx){
    width = width - 10;
    height = height - 10;
    $(this).css({
        width: width + '%',
        height: height + '%'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var inside_element = $('figure');
var width = '90',
    height = '90';

inside_element.each(function(indx){
    $(this).css({
        width: width + '%',
        height: height + '%'
    });
    width = width - 10;
    height = height - 10;
});
```

Comment: Your answer is very rushed. You are missing %

Comment: Ups, I was thinking in pixels, that's why I left that out

Comment: The above solution using the index parameter is more clever anyway